# I have tried multiple ways, Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I am trying to make a random quote generator that generates a quote by the click of a button. I think I have done everything right, but once the button is clicked nothing happens.

Here is the code

**HTML code**

```
<div class="quote-box">
   <p id = "quote-generator"> this is where the quote will go </p>
   <button class="btn" onclick="function newQuote()"> Next </button>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
var list =  [
'/"Your mind will always believe what you tell it. Feed it faith. Feed it the truth. Feed it with love. /"',
'/"A problem is a chance for you to do your best./"',
'/"Learn how to be happy with what you have while you pursue all that you want./"',];`

const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*list.lenght);

function newQuote() {

document.getElementById("quotes-generator").innerHTML = list [randomNumber];`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your example no need to escape character in array. If single quote `'` inside in your array value you need escape character.
2. End of array you have extra `,`  .
3. Wrong way to call function on button click.

```js
var list = ['"Your mind will always believe what you tell it. Feed it faith. Feed it the truth. Feed it with love. "', '"A problem is a chance for you to do your best."', '"Learn how to be happy with what you have while you pursue all that you want."'];;


function newQuote() {
  let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  let rqt = list[rnd];
  document.getElementById("quote-generator").innerHTML = rqt;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-box">
  <p id="quote-generator"> this is where the quote will go </p> <button class="btn" onclick="newQuote()"> Next </button>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Shree, I can't thankyou enough for this solution you provided, It solved  weeks of confusion in two minutes.  thankyou thankyou thankyou!!! I am still new to js as you can tell, is it possible that you let me know why you changed certain codes in the js as opposed to the functions I had provided? I need to write about it for a report.

Comment: 1.`const` is a signal that the identifier won't be reassigned. `let` is a signal that the variable may be reassigned, such as a counter in a loop, or a value swap in an algorithm if needed.
2.Assigne  result to variable, if needed use that variable , much faster than whole process to get value. ...................

Comment: Hope you get your answer :)

Comment: I did. It makes so much sense now.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Mistakes in code

- Function call should be done on click with `onclick="newQuote()"` and not with `onclick="function newQuote()"`
- Typo error in taking the length of list to generate random number. It should be `const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);` and not `const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.lenght);`
- Id specified in HTML was `quote-generator` and in script was `quotes-generator`. They must be same.
- Also you can move the random number generation logic to inside of the function to generate new random number each time the user clicks the button. Current random number generation happens only once and the value will not update when the user clicks the button

```js
var list = [
    '/"Your mind will always believe what you tell it. Feed it faith. Feed it the truth. Feed it with love. /"', 
    '/"A problem is a chance for you to do your best./"', 
    '/"Learn how to be happy with what you have while you pursue all that you want./"',
];


function newQuote() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    document.getElementById("quote-generator").innerHTML = list[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-box">
    <p id="quote-generator"> this is where the quote will go </p> <button class="btn" onclick="newQuote()">
        Next </button>

</div>
```

The minimal representation of your solution will be

```js
const list = [
    '"Your mind will always believe what you tell it. Feed it faith. Feed it the truth. Feed it with love. "',
    '"A problem is a chance for you to do your best."',
    '"Learn how to be happy with what you have while you pursue all that you want."',
];
newQuote = () => document.getElementById("quote-generator").innerHTML = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
```

```html
<div class="quote-box">
    <p id="quote-generator">
        this is where the quote will go
    </p>
    <button class="btn" onclick="newQuote()"> Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for taking your time and helping someone out. It really helped. :)

Comment: @heleni Eventhough I provided the solution that you need at the earliest, its sad to see that you approved some other answer who posted after mine.

Answer (score 1):

> `const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*list.lenght);`

It should be list.length and not list.lenght.

Comment: Oh My God, I have worked on this for months now. thankyou. is there anything wrong with the array. because it still doesn't work. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid repetitions, it is probably a better idea to shuffle the array once and then present it to the user in a cycling fashion:

```js
/* Randomize array in-place using Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm */
function shuffleArray(array) {
for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i],array[j]] = [array[j],array[i]];
}
}
const list = [
    '"Your mind will always believe what you tell it. Feed it faith. Feed it the truth. Feed it with love. "', 
    '"A problem is a chance for you to do your best."', 
    '"Learn how to be happy with what you have while you pursue all that you want."',
]; 
shuffleArray(list);
list.n=-1;
document.querySelector(".btn").onclick=newQuote;

function newQuote(){
  document.getElementById("quote-generator").innerHTML = list[++list.n%list.length];
}
newQuote();
```

```html
<div class="quote-box">
  <p id="quote-generator"> this is where the quote will go </p> 
  <button class="btn"> Next </button>
</div>
```